# Connection error(connection ECONNREFUSED) while connecting to SQL Server where installed in VMware Fusion

Tags: sql, sql-server, virtual-machine, telnet, remote-server

I build REST API for connecting to a SQL Server where installed vmware fusion. When ı tried to connect remote SQL Server  port 1433 it will throw an error:

> "Failed to connect to 192.168.1.20:1433 - connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.1.20:1433"

- 192.168.1.20 -> This is my bridge network ip adress with vmware fusion.
- 1433 -> This is the SQL Server port number.

I am also look is the port open with telnet. I install the telnet and execute the following code in terminal :

```
telnet 192.168.1.20 1433
```

and this is the same error.

```
Trying 192.168.1.20... 

telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.20 : Connection refused
```

> telnet: Unable to connect to remote host.

So I cannot reach the remote SQL Server installed in vmware fusion.

This is my db.cs file:

```
exports.dbConfig = {
    user:"username",
    password:"111111",
    server:"192.168.1.20",
    database:"dbname",
    port: 1433
};
```

How can I fix this error?